# kubectl get: The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused -Kubernetes

Tags: docker, networking, kubernetes

Running a baremetal master. Trying to set it up. Looked at the other answers - the hostname is in place - everything. And still...

```
[root@kube-future kubernetes]# kubectl get
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you 
specify the right host or port?
```

UPDATE

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10251         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5854/kube-scheduler 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:2379          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5763/etcd           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10252         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5814/kube-controlle 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:2380          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5763/etcd           
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1419/sshd           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1508/master         
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10248         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5531/kubelet        
tcp6       0      0 :::10250                :::*                    LISTEN      5531/kubelet        
tcp6       0      0 :::6443                 :::*                    LISTEN      5812/kube-apiserver 
tcp6       0      0 :::10255                :::*                    LISTEN      5531/kubelet        
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1419/sshd           
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN      1508/master
```

this is the result of env update 2:

```
LC_PAPER=cs_CZ.UTF-8
XDG_SESSION_ID=80
LC_ADDRESS=cs_CZ.UTF-8
HOSTNAME=kube-future
LC_MONETARY=cs_CZ.UTF-8
TERM=xterm
SHELL=/bin/bash
HISTSIZE=1000
SSH_CLIENT=10.194.4.254 44190 22
LC_NUMERIC=cs_CZ.UTF-8
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/0
USER=root                               LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=01;05;37;41:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.axv=01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=01;36:*.au=01;36:*.flac=01;36:*.mid=01;36:*.midi=01;36:*.mka=01;36:*.mp3=01;36:*.mpc=01;36:*.ogg=01;36:*.ra=01;36:*.wav=01;36:*.axa=01;36:*.oga=01;36:*.spx=01;36:*.xspf=01;36:
LC_TELEPHONE=cs_CZ.UTF-8
MAIL=/var/spool/mail/root
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin
LC_IDENTIFICATION=cs_CZ.UTF-8
PWD=/root
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=cs_CZ.UTF-8
HISTCONTROL=ignoredups
SHLVL=1
HOME=/root
no_proxy=$no_proxy,10.194.110.4
LOGNAME=root
SSH_CONNECTION=10.194.4.254 44190 10.194.110.4 22
LESSOPEN=||/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/0
LC_NAME=en_US.UTF-8
_=/usr/bin/env
```

`kubectl config view` --> https://pastebin.com/sgbnyp8F

Comment: `telnet localhost 8080` and `sudo netstat -plnt`. See the output of this and see if kubernetes is even running or not

Comment: [root@kube-future ~]# telnet localhost 8080
   Trying ::1...
   telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
   Trying 127.0.0.1...
   telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused

Comment: and the netstat one?

Comment: updated the first post

Comment: also please add the output of `env` command

Comment: difficult to debug without more information, like how did you configure the API server. It does seem like it is listening on 6443, so trying to reach it on 8080 will definitely not work, except if you configured a no-auth insecure port on 8080.

Comment: updateed the first post

Comment: your problem is $HOME/.kube/config file is missing. how did you create the cluster? can you post the command?

Comment: i followed this manual https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/#configure-kubectl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same.

Running the following command as suggested [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kubernetes-users/2EJ-i7vLVNw) solved my problem.

```
sudo cp /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/
sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/admin.conf
export KUBECONFIG=$HOME/admin.conf
```